# Vim remaps only work if inside of a function

Tags: vim

I'm attempting to enable navigation based on displayed lines in VIM with `set wrap linebreak` enabled.

I have this [function](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip38), which will toggle line wrapping with `<Leader-W>`

```
noremap <silent> <Leader>w :call ToggleWrap()<CR>
function ToggleWrap()
  if &wrap
    echo "Wrap OFF"
    setlocal nowrap
    set virtualedit=all
    silent! nunmap <buffer> <Up>
    silent! nunmap <buffer> <Down>
    silent! nunmap <buffer> <Home>
    silent! nunmap <buffer> <End>
    silent! iunmap <buffer> <Up>
    silent! iunmap <buffer> <Down>
    silent! iunmap <buffer> <Home>
    silent! iunmap <buffer> <End>
  else
    echo "Wrap ON"
    setlocal wrap linebreak nolist
    set virtualedit=
    setlocal display+=lastline
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <Up>   gk
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <Down> gj
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <Home> g<Home>
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <End>  g<End>
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <Up>   <C-o>gk
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <Down> <C-o>gj
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <Home> <C-o>g<Home>
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <End>  <C-o>g<End>
  endif
endfunction
```

This works perfectly. But I want to have wrap and linebreak enabled all the time and have this navigation mappings work. So I removed the function and left this.

```
    set wrap linebreak nolist
    set virtualedit=
    set display+=lastline
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <Up>   gk
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <Down> gj
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <Home> g<Home>
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <End>  g<End>
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <Up>   <C-o>gk
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <Down> <C-o>gj
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <Home> <C-o>g<Home>
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <End>  <C-o>g<End>
```

Normal mode works fine, but insert mode does not. Any reason why this isn't working outside of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. A plugin may override the insert mode mappings; check with `:verbose imap <Up>`.
2. Your mappings will only work in the *first* buffer; for global configuration, drop the `<buffer>` from the `:map` commands (like you switched `:setlocal` to `:set`).

Comment: Didn't even think about the first option. Turns out that YouCompleteMe was overriding up and down. Thanks!